# Wildcards in ServiceWorker / Cache API

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, cacheapi

I am using ServiceWorker and in dev mode works perfectly, my problem is that in production mode my bundle name is generated using hash, e.g. `1234das3123ad5.bundle.js`, so the service worker is not caching it. My sw code looks like:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // pre cache a load of stuff:
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('mycache').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/dist/bundle.js',
        '/dist/app.css',
        '/dist/index.html',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/2.7.2/antd.css'
      ]);
    })
  )
});
```

In the docs of [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/addAll) I dont see any example on how I can achieve that.

Obviously I could cache everything under the `dist` folder, having something like:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // pre cache a load of stuff:
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('mycache').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/dist/',
      ]);
    })
  )
});
```

But I dont find it an elegant, good in long term, solution. Is it a way to have wild cards in the Cache? Something like `'/dist/*.bundle.js'` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web doesn't have the concept of folders, specifically there isn't a way for a browser to know all the valid URLs starting with a prefix.

The rest of your site must be handling the URL changes for revisioning assets somehow, so why not use the same solution in your service worker?

That's what I did for my blog - Django's static file manager adds the correct URLs https://jakearchibald.com/sw.js

Comment: thx Jake, I would probably find a way with webpack to generate the correct urls on the fly.

Comment: so what you're saying is that the sw.js is dynamically generated/modified based on the generated bundle names  through webpack or some other method like sed/awk?

Comment: Sure, or you could load the names using `fetch('files.json').then(r => r.json())`

Comment: Hey @JaffaTheCake, I'm trying to cache an ajax call from datatable except the ajax call appends a random generated key of digits at the end of it, the response has this also. Caching that results in a new entry each time and never a match because the key is random each time. Do you know what I mean? If there's a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple Node script that will create the array of filenames for you, provided you want a list of every file in your web/public directory. NOTE: you want to run this from a terminal at your `public` directory.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
var walk = function(dir, done) {
    var results = [];
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        var i = 0;
        (function next() {
            var file = list[i++];
            if (!file) return done(null, results);
            //file = dir + '/' + file;
            file = path.resolve(dir, file);
            fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
                if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(file, function(err, res) {
                        results = results.concat(res);
                        next();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    file = file.replace('/home/ubuntu/workspace/public', '');
                    results.push(file);
                    next();
                }
            });
        })();
    });
};
var mydir = path.resolve(__dirname);
walk(mydir, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(util.inspect(results, { maxArrayLength: null }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing some issues with this, with a vue3 pwa.
So this is not a true answer, but rather a hopefully valuable reply.

With vue3, the service worker file that is generated, includes:

```
importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.\<something-something\>.js"
);
```

and the precache-manifest.js file that is generated, lists all the js, css and font stuff that is built when doing a "vue-cli-serve build", e.g. something like:

```
self.__precacheManifest = (self.__precacheManifest || []).concat([
  {
    "revision": "f715169493da60af08a445c4f7990905",
    "url": "/.htaccess"
  },
  {
    "revision": "87260e830ed912c46685c0a5432addf2",
    "url": "/.well-known/web-app-origin-association"
  },
<snip>
```

The workbox script then takes this list and caches the mentioned files.